# ': not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have removed the two if statements from before and replaced them with a case statement and tried to remove all the error from the code.
I am trying to run this code but i get an error in the case statement.
"': not a valid identifier
main.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''

'ain.sh: line 5:`case "$y" in   "

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo "1. Julian"
echo "2. Gregorian"
read y
case "$y" in
1)echo "Enter your year (1900-2050)"
read x
if [[ $x -ge 1900 && $x -le 2050 ]]
 then
a=$((x%19)) 
b=$((x/100))
c=$((x%100))
d=$((b/4))
e=$((b%4))
g=$(((8*b+13)/25))
h=$(((19*a+b-d-g+15)%30))
m=$(((a+11*h)/319))
j=$((c/4))
k=$((c%4))
l=$(((2*e+2*j-k-h+m+32)%7))
n=$(((h-m+l+90)/25))
p=$(((h-m+l+n+19)%32)) 
o=$(date +"$x-$n-$p")

echo "Gregorian Easter is on $O."

else
 echo "Invalid Input" 
 fi
;;

2) echo "Enter your year (1900-2050)"
read x
if [[ $x -ge 1900 && $x -le 2050 ]]
 then
A=$((x%4)) 
B=$((x%7))
C=$((x%19))
D=$(((19*C+15)%30))
E=$(((2*A+4*B−D+34)%7))
M=$(((D+E+114)/31))
day=$(((D+E+115)%31))
o=$(date +"$x-$M-$day")

echo "Gregorian Easter is on $o."
else 
 echo "Invalid Input"
fi
;;
0) exit ;;
esac
```

Comment: There's too many errors in your code, Try balancing the if statement first. You can't balance 3 ifs with just one fi

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: is this a way to learn the shell?  not a useful demonstration in the shell.  if you're doing arithmetic, take this computation-intensive problem to awk.  avoid the syntactic noise the shell imposes on arithmetic.  (unless manipulating file names).

Answer (score 6):

#### Addressing the issue in the title, `': not a valid identifier`

This happens when `read` is passed a variable name that ends with a carriage return symbol.

When that symbol is printed, it sends the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

Thus, `read foo<CR>` tries to print:

```
foo<CR>': not a valid identifier
```

However, because `<CR>` sends the cursor back, what it *actually* prints is:

```
': not a valid identifier
```

To fix this, run `dos2unix` on your file; run `:set fileformat=unix` in vim, or otherwise transform it to have UNIX newlines instead of DOS newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash`.

Replace `elif[` with `elif [`.

Add a `fi` line above the `elif` line.

Add a `then` line below the `elif` line.

Replace `-gt` with `-ge`.

Replace `-lt` with `-le`.

Having done this your `o` variable may still end up empty, but you can debug that by adding `echo +"$x-$n-$p"`.

Answer (score 0):

Still, there were too many errors. Anyway, I think you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "1. Julian"
echo "2. Gregorian"
read y
case "$y" in
1)echo "Enter your year (1900-2050)"
read x
if [[ $x -ge 1900 && $x -le 2050 ]]; then
a=$((x%19)) 
b=$((x/100))
c=$((x%100))
d=$((b/4))
e=$((b%4))
g=$(((8*b+13)/25))
h=$(((19*a+b-d-g+15)%30))
m=$(((a+11*h)/319))
j=$((c/4))
k=$((c%4))
l=$(((2*e+2*j-k-h+m+32)%7))
n=$(((h-m+l+90)/25))
p=$(((h-m+l+n+19)%32)) 
o="$date $x-$n-$p"

echo "Julian Easter is on $o."

else
 echo "Invalid Input" 
 fi
;;

2) echo "Enter your year (1900-2050)"
read x
if [[ $x -ge 1900 && $x -le 2050 ]]; then
A=$((x%4)) 
B=$((x%7))
C=$((x%19))
D=$(((19*C+15)%30))
E=$(((2*A+4*B-D+34)%7))
M=$(((D+E+114)/31))
day=$(((D+E+115)%31))
o="$date $x-$M-$day"

echo "Gregorian Easter is on $o."
else 
 echo "Invalid Input"
fi
;;
0) exit
;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

One input here-
I was facing same issue for one of my scripts. I found one blunder I have done.
Always make sure function names should not have - and instead _ should be used.