# This shell script is not working, code is right but it gives error each time

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix, syntax

```
echo "Enter Username"
read name
username = 'hagemaru'
if [ $name == $username ]
  then
    echo "Valid Username"
else
    echo "Entered Username is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Errors while executing:

```
l.sh: 3: username: not found
l.sh: 4: [: hagemaru: unexpected operator
```

Output should be:

```
Valid Username
```

Comment: Please try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `username` and `=`, otherwise bash will interpret `username` as a command (as indicated in the error message) which doesn't exist. Doing this, you also need to remove the space between `username=` and `'hagemaru'` as bash will interpret `username= 'hagemaru'` as running the command `username=` with a parameter of `'hagemaru'` which is not valid as there is no `username=` command in bash.

```
echo "Enter Username"
read name
username='hagemaru'
if [ $name == $username ]
  then
    echo "Valid Username"
else
    echo "Entered Username is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Still this error is coming: Login.sh: 4: [: hagemaru: unexpected operator

Comment: Did you also remove the space between `=` and `'hagemaru'`? Try using the code in my answer.

Comment: I tried your code still the same issue.

Comment: I don't think so. The code works fine. Maybe you failed to save the file or something.

Comment: Try executing the code here to see that it works. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell

Comment: Error: Enter Username
': not a valid identifier`name
main.bash: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Are you sure you are copying the code in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this in different terminals. Same issue.

Comment: Can you tell me where you are testing this code.

Comment: I tested the code with my bash interpreter as well as in the one available at this site that I mentioned above https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell

Comment: @RishabParashar The "not a valid identifier" error suggests your script has DOS/Windows line endings rather than unix; see ["': not a valid identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576654/not-a-valid-identifier) and ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) Also, in a `[ ]` test expression, `==` is nonstandard (although some shells tollerate it); use `=` instead.

Comment: @RishabParashar Are you sure the script is run by `bash` not `sh`? POSIX compatible shells require `=` instead of `==`. Maybe insert a line `#! /bin/bash`